# Tooltip with MySQL query

Tags: php, ajax

I have problem with tooltip.

I have some rows in table

```
echo '<td><center>'.$dana['material'].'</td>';
echo '<td><center>'.$zmiennacal.'</td>';
$mat=$dana['material'];
```

and now its my question, can I do a dynamic tooltip with MySQL query like this

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(CONNECTION QUERY);
$zapytanie = "SELECT iloscsurmaterialu, Produkt FROM receptaprodukt WHERE surowiec='$mat'"
or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $zapytanie);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo  "'.$row['iloscsurmaterialu'].' - '.$row['Produkt'].'";
}
```

and take this result in tooltip, in second row in my table where is `$zmiennacal`

I'm trying some scripts but no one works :( (i know that it must be in ajax but I don't know that structure as PHP :P

Thank you in advance, please HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use ajax. You need to have a 'event' that triggers the ajax. Maybe a hover will work?

```
<?php
//ajax php file
$mat = $_POST['mat'];
$sql = 'SELECT iloscsurmaterialu, Produkt FROM receptaprodukt WHERE surowiec = :mat';
// to see where $dbh comes from: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':mat' => $mat));
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
$title = '';
if(!$result){
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
    exit;
}
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $title .= "'".$row['iloscsurmaterialu'].' - '.$row['Produkt']."'";
}
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'title' => $title
));
exit;



//jQuery post: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
$('body').on('hover', '#mytable td', function(){
    $td = $(this);
    $td.attr('title', 'Loading...');
    var mat = $(this).data('mat');
    $.post( "ajax/get_title.php", {"mat" : mat}, function( data ) {
        if(data && data.success){
            var title = data.title;
            $td.attr('title', title); //note that td is not specific, it will add title to all the tds. You need to select the correct one.
        }
    }, "json");
});

//Html
$mat = $dana['material'];
echo '<td data-mat = "'.$mat.'"><center>'.$mat.'</td>';
echo '<td><center>'.$zmiennacal.'</td>';
```

Comment: And if i have more than one rows in tooltip querry it doesnt show in tooltip

Comment: I'm not sure how your table structure is. But I updated my answer. Maybe it's wrong. I'm not sure since I don't know your database structure.

Comment: But it must be in Ajax couse i cant multiple $zmiennacal.
i take my toolip from view in PHPmyadmin (from another table)

Comment: but i dont know how to put $mat in {mat: 'somemat'}

Comment: Hello, i take your new code set te id in my table
     id='mytable' put
     data-mat = "'.$mat.'" in td
and it doesnt work i missed something?

Comment: and i set class="result" please help if it doesnt work on hover it can be on click

Comment: What can you see in the javascript console? Put some console.log in the code to find out what is happening

Comment: Yeah, now its working, answer is hover is not an event i must use mouseenter. but i have another problem...

im using this tooltip:
[link](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

and when i hover i have tooltip with "Loading..." and have another normal title with answer from script, there are any way to replace Loading with answer?

Comment: Maybe make another question then? Link it here and I'll see if I can help. Or some else will :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh sorry on my phone I didn't see your whole comment. Maybe try disable then enable method as seen here? http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip

Comment: Ehhh the same... It is caused by tooltip? couse normaly it shoudl replace title for sure?

Comment: Yes but i see too, aria-describebdby="ui-id-x" what its means ? i dont know ajax very well... :(

Comment: aria-describedby is the id of the tooltip div. I can't really help you unless I can see what's wrong. You can either show me or maybe this example will help? https://jsbin.com/rufamusesi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please fix `$zapytanie` SQL injection.

Comment: Done, I was just being lazy